# Getting a Choose Country to work

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make it possible such that when a person as soon as he clicks his country he will get redirected to a subdomain of my website. You can see it at www.test.answercup.com , but when I choose the country nothing happens. I want to make it so that when he clicks his country that page gets redirected to the respective subdomain. How do I do that?

The code that I used -

```
<div class="container2"> 
    <span class="select">
        <select>
            <option value disabled selected>Select country</option>
            <option value="be">Sri Lanka</option>
            <option value="ne">Pakistan</option>
        </select>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry I put . in the code because I dont know how to display the code otherwise.

Comment: Works fine for me on your website.

Comment: The posted code does nothing. It just lets the user select an option, but this selection has no impact on anything. You must have some other code that is really meant to *do* something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a **`onchange event`** for select box

```
<select id="selectbox" name="" onchange="javascript:location.href = this.value;">
    <option value="https://www.yahoo.com/" selected>Option1</option>
    <option value="https://www.google.co.in/">Option2</option>
    <option value="https://www.gmail.com/">Option3</option>
</select>
```

**OR**

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="selectbox" name="">
    <option value="https://www.yahoo.com/" selected>Option1</option>
    <option value="https://www.google.co.in/">Option2</option>
    <option value="https://www.gmail.com/">Option3</option>
</select>

<script>
$(function(){
    $("#selectbox").change(function()
    {
        document.location.href = $(this).val();
    });
});
</script>
```